# Как реализовать кнопки над клавиатурой?

Tags: ios

Как реализовать кнопки над клавиатурой?(например: приложение "Заметки")

Нашел только упоминание **Accessory Input View**.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889368/possible-to-programmatically-feed-the-ios-predictive-keyboard-context-source-tex

Comment: а что вообще надо сделать? чтоб suggestions  появились? это по моему в настройках телефона. возможно надо для того вью, к которому вы хотите suggestions включить автокоррект.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko нет, я не про suggestions, а про кнопку привязанную к клавиатуре.

Comment: тогда по ссылке выше вроде подходящий ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно `inputAccessoryView` тут и нужен. Вот небольшой пример из жизни.

```
UIToolbar *tbKbd = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
UIBarButtonItem *btDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                        target:self
                                                                        action:@selector(yourHandler)];
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                        target:nil
                                                                        action:nil]
tbKbd.items = @[spacer, btDone];
textField.inputAccessoryView = tbKbd;
```

В результате получится аккуратная панелька с кнопкой выше клавиатуры. `spacer` нужен только для того, чтобы сместить кнопку к правому краю клавиатуры. Кнопка будет с надписью Готово, но можно сделать с любой надписью, со значком - что угодно, любой `UIBarButtonItem`. Можно вообще свой прозрачный `UIView` сделать вместо тулбара, как хотите :)